# Get data on Array (Codeigniter)

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, foreach

Hello im new in codeigniter
please help

i have array looking like this

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [A] => MEMBER EMAIL 
                       [B] => MEMBER GENDER (M/F) 
                       [C] => COMPANY ID 
                       [D] => COUNTRY 
                       [E] => DOB 
                       [F] => MOBILE NUMBER 
                       [G] => ADDRESS 
                       [H] => POINTS 
                       [I] => STATUS ) 
        [2] => Array ( [A] => tollars@mailinator.com 
                       [B] => M 
                       [C] => 1 
                       [D] => Indonesia 
                       [E] => 1998-05-02 
                       [F] => 8734683784 
                       [G] => Address Here 
                       [H] => 100 
                       [I] => 1 ) 
        [3] => Array ( [A] => tollars2@mailinator.com 
                       [B] => F 
                       [C] => 9 
                       [D] => Singapore 
                       [E] => 1998-05-02 
                       [F] => 94598859430 
                       [G] => Address Here 
                       [H] => 10 
                       [I] => 1 ) 
      )
```

i want to get like this

```
array("MEMBER EMAIL ", "tollars@mailinator.com","tollars2@mailinator.com")
```

sorry for my english
thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will work for you :

```
$data = 'your given array';
foreach ($data as $rows) {
   foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
      if ($key == 'A')
      {
          $result[] = $row;
      }   
   }

}
print_r($result);
```

will output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => MEMBER EMAIL
    [1] => tollars@mailinator.com
    [2] => tollars2@mailinator.com
)
```

Comment: thanks, but the format is like this array("MEMBER EMAIL ", "tollars@mailinator.com","tollars2@mailinator.com")

Comment: this is the same format you put it as raw and i show you as  view source